# How can we view the column names and other metadata for a [DataBricks] Delta-Table?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

A `Spark DataFrame` has the `.columns` attribute:

`dataFrame.columns`

A `DeltaTable` does not. Note that the latter is based off a `parquet` file/directory and `parquet`s are self-describing so the columnar info *is* available at the least in the files themselves. So the columnar info *should* be accessible/available from the `DeltaTable`. I just have not been able to find anything even by going deep into its protected/private attributes with a debugger. I wonder what is the way to work with these constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of the `DeltaTable` object has the `.toDF` function ([doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.toDF)) that could be used to create a DataFrame instance on which you can call `.columns`.

```py
tbl = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "...")
tbl.toDF().columns
```

P.S. Although it would be nice to extend the `.detail` function to return the table's schema - maybe you can file a feature request for it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way that I know is as below using sql syntax but you could also write that inside spark.sql.

Describe table extended tablename

Executing above command will give you all the details about the column name, data type, comments, physical location of parquet files, partitioning information if any and many more details.

Comment: I was asking about the api construct `DeltaTable` that is available in `scala` and `pyspark`.  I think your suggestion would require creating a `DataFrame` and then doing something like `createOrReplaceTempView()`   That's possible but is also not the intent of the question which is to avoid all that additional overhead.